# How to append ORDERBY with where condition in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working with mysql and Rest Api in php,I want to use "orderby" according to condition (if "filterId"==3 or 4). In other words:

1. If I pass filterId='3' then query should be like `SELECT ......ORDER by p.sp ASC/DESC`
2. If I pass filterId='4' then query should be like `SELECT ......ORDER by m.merchantName ASC/DESC`
3. If I pass both parameters,filterId='3' and filterId='4' then query should be like `SELECT ......ORDER by m.merchantName,p.sp ASC/DESC`
4. If not pass filterId='3' or filterId='4' then orderby not apply/append

How can I do this? Here is my current code:

```
if(isset($_GET["Filter"]))
            {
                $filter=trim($_GET['Filter']);
                $data=json_decode($filter);
               // echo "<pre>";print_R($data);
                foreach($data as $dt)
                    {   
                        foreach($dt as $d)
                            {
                                //echo $d->filter_id;
                                if($d->filter_id=="1")
                                {
                                    
                                }
                                if($d->filter_id=="3")
                                {
                                    
                                }
                                }
}
```

Comment: *if i pass both parameters,filterId='3' and filterId='4'* ??? How one variable can have two different values at the same time?

Comment: @Akina: i want if we pass two parameters then query should be like

"ORDER BY p.sp,m.merchantName ASC/DESC "

Comment: Your question is **Unclear**. Please show different samples of `$data` which represents all of your described scenarios.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
    $query = "Select * from .... ORDER BY";
        
        if(isset($_GET["Filter"]))
                    {
                        $filter=trim($_GET['Filter']);
                        $data=json_decode($filter);
                       // echo "<pre>";print_R($data);
                        foreach($data as $dt)
                            {   
                                foreach($dt as $d)
                                    {
                                        //echo $d->filter_id;
                                        if($d->filter_id=="1")
                                        {
                                           $query .='ORDER BY p.asp'; 
                                        }
                                        else if($d->filter_id=="3")
                                        {
                                            $query .='ORDER BY m.merchantName'; 
                                        }
                                        else 
                                        {
                                            break;
                                        }
        
                                        }
        }
```

For your third condition, you might have to use in_array_all() as below:

```
function in_array_all($lookfor, $mainarray) {
   return empty(array_diff($lookfor, $mainarray));
}
```

Comment: how can i use "ASC" AND "Desc" in this condition

Comment: and if i pass both "filterid='3' and filterid='4' ...then ?

Comment: You can save in these variables $order_by_p.asp =  'p.asp ASC';  OR $order_by_p.asp =  'p.asp DESC'; depending on your logic of when to use ASC or DESC.

Comment: for both values, filter id cannot be 3 and 4 at the same time unless it's an array even then it would contain both values but on different indexes, so you will have to check if 3 and 4 exist in an array and execute the logic.

Comment: This is not valid php code and `empty()` should be replaced with `!` to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score -2):

```
//Try this    
$query = 'select * from ...';
    $order_by_clause = '';
    
    if(isset($_GET["Filter"]))
    {
       $filter=trim($_GET['Filter']);
       $data=json_decode($filter);
       foreach($data as $dt)
       {   
          foreach($dt as $d)
          {
             //echo $d->filter_id;
             if($d->filter_id=="3")
             {
                $order_by_clause = 'ORDER BY p.sp ASC';
             }
             else if($d->filter_id=="4")
             {
                $order_by_clause = 'ORDER BY m.merchantName';
             }
             else if(($d->filter_id=="3") && if($d->filter_id=="4"))
             {
                $order_by_clause = 'ORDER BY m.merchantName,p.sp';
             }
             else if(!(($d->filter_id!="3") || if($d->filter_id!="4"))
             {
                $order_by_clause = '';
             }
          }
       }
    }
    
    $query .= $order_by_clause;
```

Comment: Please never post code-only answers on Stack Overflow.  `elseif` is one word in PHP.

Comment: `if(($d->filter_id=="3") && if($d->filter_id=="4"))` is not valid PHP.  By the way, how can `$d->filter_id` equal `3` and `4` at the same time?!?